# Triggering update of parent component on child state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am exploring firebase using React as a frontend framework and got stuck on a following problem:

I have the following parent component with a lifecycle hook that gets my data from firebase and populates a local state with it. After that the component outputs the state .

```
state = {
    pets: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    db
      .onceGetPets()
      .then(snapshot => this.setState(() => ({ pets: snapshot.val() })));
  }

  render() {
    const {pets} = this.state;
     return ({pets})}
```

I also have a child component that writes new entries into the data base and looks the following way:

```
state = {
    ...INITIAL_STATE
  };

  submitHandler = event => {
    const { name, age, animal, breed } = this.state;

    db.doCreatePet(
      name,
      age,
      animal,
      breed,
      auth.currentUser.email.slice(0, -4)
    );
    this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
    event.preventDefault();
  };
    render(){
      return(<StyledNewPetForm show={this.props.show} onSubmit={this.submitHandler}/>)}
```

I want to achieve the following behavior:

When user submits the form(child component) it should trigger rerender of parent component(the one that displays data) that would in turn get new data from firebase and display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling the pets data in componentDidMount, move it to separate function like below and bind the function in the constructor.

```
fetchPetData(){
 db
      .onceGetPets()
      .then(snapshot => this.setState(() => ({ pets: snapshot.val() })));
}
```

and call the function in componentDidMount as below

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPetData();
  }
```

Then you can pass the function as props to child component and call the function in child component in submit function as below.

```
this.props.fetchPetData();
```

and in the parent component

```
<Child fetchPetdata={this.fetchPetData} />
```

Comment: Can I trigger several functions on onChange even then?

Comment: Yes you can. But again performance issue if you are doing lot of changes in onChange event. Try to use onChange event for validation alone and onSubmit for final data submission.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be passing a function prop to the parent component which you'd call on update. So in your child function you have something like

```
submitHandler = event => {
  const { name, age, animal, breed } = this.state;

  db.doCreatePet(
    name,
    age,
    animal,
    breed,
    auth.currentUser.email.slice(0, -4)
  );
  this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
  event.preventDefault();
  this.props.reloadData(); // Add this
};
```

while in the parent component's render function you'd have

```
fetchData() {
  db
    .onceGetPets()
    .then(snapshot => this.setState(() => ({ pets: snapshot.val() })));
}
```

and in the render method you'd

```
render() {
  return (
    <Child reloadData={this.fecthData} ...props/>
  )
}
```